# How to permanently change color on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that changes the color of a box on button click and it works fine. My question is when I reload the page the CSS will revert back to the original box color. Is there a way to make the changed box color permanent. Even when the page is reloaded the changed color will not revert back.Can't use local storage and cookies because those are not shared between devices.Something like changing the whole codebase when the function `changeColor` runs. Is this possible. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.button1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<button class="button1" onclick="changeColor()">Change color</button>
```

Comment: Use a cookie or localStorage

Comment: It's possible when you save the information about the clicked button in a cookie...

Comment: But what if the user uses a different device to access the site the cookie won't. @TJ

Comment: @hamtonko then use a backend and store it in database

Comment: Any suggestions on how to push the document to the backend?@TJ

Answer (score 1):

use this function

1.store color value with key backgroundColor

```
localStorage.setItem("backgroundColor","red");
```

2.access it from local storage

```
localStorage.getItem("backgroundColor");
```

3.clear the local storage (optional when needed)

```
localStorage.clear();
```

now you can access color from local storage.

Comment: will this work if the user access the website from a different device? @Haker Baya

Comment: yes, it will be stored in his browser storage.

Comment: if you wanna store into cookie. here is code `document.cookie = "color=red";` but best practice is to store in local storage.

Comment: It won't work from a different device. LocalStorage is only persistent on the current device and it is not shared between devices.

Comment: That's what I wanted though any suggestions on how to access the saved storage on different devices? @BasilAiman

Comment: i am prettly sure, it will get stored in user's browser storage, i have already used  this and color will get only removed from users's storage when user will clear the browser storage, cache or history. hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, it will get stored in the browser storage but that browser storage is only accessible to one browser so if the user opens the site from a different device browser the saved storage is not there anymore? Haker Baya

Comment: if you have already added the code localStorage.setItem("key","value") into script, script gets executed and store the color in browser memory even on a different device, because you are adding this code statically, it is not dynamic coming from any client or server. :)

Answer (score 0):

Then I think you have to save the changed color into browser cookie or localstorage. And when you are loading the page, take the color from the cookie/localstorage. If there is no color saved then render the div with the default color.

Here's a pseudo code.

```
function changeColor() {
  // save the color in localstorage or cookie
  document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```
function onLoad() {
  // const desiredColor = (read color from localstorage or cookie) || "red";
  document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = desiredColor;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain which part of the code is setting the cookie?

Comment: Actually, I just gave a pseudo code here. The full solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67425460/11747697

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your local machine.

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.cookie = "green";
  document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function getColor() {
  document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor = document.cookie || "red";
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.button1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" onload="getColor()"></div>
<button class="button1" onclick="changeColor()">Change color</button>
```

Comment: But what if the user accesses the site from a different device? Setting a cookie will only save the data on 1 browser. Cookie data is not shared across multiple devices.@Showrin Barua

Comment: Yes... Cookie or localstorage data can't be shared in different devices or browsers. If you want to share data among different devices, then you have store this value into a database.